# Email providers with support for high privacy?

Tags: email, security, privacy

I am looking for an email provider which (1 alt A) supports end-to-end encryption of emails, alternatively (1 alt B) that they work well with something like Thunderbird so that I can encrypt messages on my own computer before sending, or (1 alt C) integrates with a "security wrapper" like "Mailvelop" which can encrypt messages. It's important that I can (2) communicate with my friends who are using PGP at the moment. And also that  (3) the email servers are located in a country with strong privacy laws (like Switzerland)

Basically what I'm looking for is a secure way to communicate via email where I don't have to set up my own email server

I've looked at *ProtonMail* (based in Switzerland) but unfortunately they [do not support PGP](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/sending-a-message-using-pgppgp/) and [doesn't work with third-party clients](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/third-party-email-client-integration-outlook-thunderbird-apple-mail-ect/) (if a third-party client was supported this would mean that I could encrypt the messages in my own client)

Right now I am using *GMail together with the "Mailevelop" Chrome extension* which works pretty well, but the unencrypted emails are stored in places with weak privacy laws

Comment: So you are looking for an email *provider* – or for an email *application?*

Answer (score 1):

An email provider with a good reputation is...

https://posteo.de/en

...it offers end-to-end encryption. I'm using it myself and already installed a PGP certificate out of curiosity. The installation wasn't difficult, one can work with the mailvelope browser addon, though it was a bit tricky to add the certificate to the public key servers.

Additionally they also offer synchronisation of the addressbook and of the calendar, both can be stored encrypted on their server.